# Detect partial upload (WAV file)

Tags: c#, wav, file-transfer, shared-directory

Is there a way to detect if a file has only been partially uploaded in C#? Specifically, I'm talking about a WAV file, uploading to a network path (like a shared drive), which has stopped due to network issues or something.

I'm simulating this by plugging out my network cable mid-transfer. But what I find is that the file is created on the other side, but the file-size is the full file size, and even the length of the recording (which is obtained using the method below) is the full length. But when I play the file, the sound just cuts out in the middle of the file, with the remainder just continuing to play in silence (presumably where I plugged out the network cable).

Here is how I'm getting the length of the recording.

```
StringBuilder bufferLengthStr = new StringBuilder(32);

mciSendString(string.Format("open \"{0}\" type waveaudio alias wave", fileName), null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
mciSendString("status wave length", bufferLengthStr, bufferLengthStr.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);
mciSendString("close wave", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

int recordingLength = 0;
int.TryParse(bufferLengthStr.ToString(), out recordingLength);
```

Now the thing is, I know how long the file should be, but the method above returns the full length, even though that full length hasn't been filled with sound.

Comment: mciSendString returns a long. I am not sure if it's the number of bytes or an error code, so you should be able to debug and figure

Comment: @Atterson I've tried it a few times now. On one occasion the interrupted file caused the `mciSendString` to take a long time and did return an error code, which is fine. However, other times, it returned immeadiately (as if it was a normal file) with a return code = 0 and the `bufferLength` containing the full length.

Comment: So you will have to check the return code. When it takes a long time (error case), do you wait synchronously for the function to end? Might use async await. If you like I will write an answer about that.

Comment: @Attersson - that's OK, I'm not too worried about it taking a long time. But as I said, I am checking the return code and (in some cases) it's returning a 0, which according to the docs, means the call was successful and so it doesn't detect that the file transfer failed.

Comment: Ah, that is terrible. We are out of luck then. I guess you will have to implement some communication, like asking the file size from the receiver host and getting it back, then comparing. (Or trying to re-download)

Comment: No good I'm afraid... As I said, the file sizes are the same as it creates the full file at the beginning of the upload.

Comment: There is no way, unless you also save the file locally, then upload and then check by trying to download it back and compare or at least getting the size and comparing sizes. You can then get rid of the local file.